# Linux kernel: how to wait in multiple wait queues?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I know how to wait in Linux kernel queues using `wait_event` and how to wake them up.

Now I need to figure out how to wait in multiple queues at once. I need to multiplex multiple event sources, basically in a way similar to `poll` or `select`, but since the sources of events don't have the form of a pollable file descriptor, I wasn't able to find inspiration in the implementation of these syscalls.

My initial idea was to take the code from the `wait_event` macro, use `DEFINE_WAIT` multiple times as well as `prepare_to_wait`.

However, given how `prepare_to_wait` is implemented, I'm afraid the internal linked list of the queue would become corrupted if the same "waiter" is added multiple times (which could maybe happen if one queue causes wakeup, but the wait condition isn't met and waiting is being restarted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of possible scenarios for wait in several waitqueues:

```c
int ret = 0; // Result of waiting; in form 0/-err.

// Define wait objects, one object per waitqueue.
DEFINE_WAIT_FUNC(wait1, default_wake_function);
DEFINE_WAIT_FUNC(wait2, default_wake_function);

// Add ourselves to all waitqueues.
add_wait_queue(wq1, &wait1);
add_wait_queue(wq2, &wait2);

// Waiting cycle
while(1) {
    // Change task state for waiting.
    // NOTE: this should come **before** condition checking for avoid races.
    set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
    // Check condition(s) which we are waiting
    if(cond) break;
    // Need to wait
    schedule();
    // Check if waiting has been interrupted by signal
    if (signal_pending(current)) {
        ret = -ERESTARTSYS;
        break;
    }               
}
// Remove ourselves from all waitqueues.
remove_wait_queue(wq1, &wait1);
remove_wait_queue(wq2, &wait2);
// Restore task state
__set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
// 'ret' contains result of waiting.
```

Note, that this scenario is slightly different from one of `wait_event`:

`wait_event` uses `autoremove_wake_function` for wait object (created with `DEFINE_WAIT`). This function, called from `wake_up()`, removes wait object from the queue. So it is needed to *re-add* wait object into the queue *each iteration*.

But in case of multiple waitqueues it is impossible to know, which waitqueue has fired. So following this strategy would require to *re-add* **every wait object** every iteration, which is inefficient.

Instead, our scenario uses `default_wake_function` for wait object, so the object is not removed from the waitqueue on `wake_up()` call, and it is sufficient to add wait object to the queue only once, before the loop.